# Slideshow effect for an Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to do instructions activity for my applications.
I thought a slideshow with different pages.
Do I have to do different activity that are chosen with 2 buttons (left arrow, right arrow) or I have to do a single activity with different image that appeared and desappeared?

What is better?

Comment: maybe ImageSwitcher can help you.
here is a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (from support library) with your instructions pictures in one Activity will be the best choice IMHO. Elements of ViewPager (pages) can be however complex you want, Fragments with their own layouts Images, Text whatever. They can be completely different or same template with different content.

You can check [tutorial on developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) for more info.

Hope this was helpful enough.

Comment: feel free to up vote/accept if you are satisfied with solution ;)

Comment: Can I insert some text on the images?